# Hide/show jquery toggle for a Div result of a Query_post ( wordpress )

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm designing a site in which there's a page that will show posts from child categories given a certain parent category ID.
Each post's title will be a question and the content the answer.
What I would like to achieve to hide/show the answer when clicking to the question or, in other words, hiding/showing the content when clicking the title.
The main thing here is that this script must run together with a post query, as the divs are not manually created, so I can't assign a specific id or class to toggle.
The toggle must work with all the posts, no matter how many of them they are.

This is the code I'm using to query the posts from parent category ( ID 327 )

```
<div id="subcat" class="m-t-1 f13 georgia bold dark-grey">
                        <?php
                            //get all child categories for a certain category ID, then for each child category display the posts
                            $parent_cat = 327;
                            $taxonomy = 'category';
                            $cat_children = get_term_children( $parent_cat, $taxonomy );

                            if ($cat_children) {
                            foreach($cat_children as $category) {
                                $args=array(
                                  'cat' => $category,
                                  'post_type' => 'post',
                                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                                );
                                $my_query = null;
                                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {                             
                                 // echo 'Category name??' . $category;                                 
                                $cat_name = get_cat_name($category);
                                echo <<<EOD
                                <div id="x">{$cat_name}</div>   
EOD;
                                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>                               
                                    <h5 class="m-v-10"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="f13 blauet bold arial" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                    <div id="mini-content" class="f12 dark-grey w-normal arial dotted-1-bottom m-b-3"><?php the_content();?></div>
                                    <?php
                                  endwhile;
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- #subcat -->
```

What I would like is that by clcking on a (now  a link to the post), it toggles on off div id="mini-content" .

Thank you very much for your assistance.

My regards and have a nice day.

Comment: Well first things first. What have you tried? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

1 st of all, `<div id="x">{$cat_name}</div>` Where does come from the `x` ?

So, What you want to do is, when clicking on the title div (id="x") toggle the div with id="mini-content".

Make sure all elements in the page have unique ID !! If not, manage yourself to do this. You can't go further untill you have not done that !!

Then bind the click event with `id="x"` element. As your elements can be loaded after the document is rendered, use `.on()` to bind the click. So present and future "x" elements will be binded whith the click event.

If your not used to use `.on()`, check the doc http://api.jquery.com/on/

In the handler function `$(document).on("click","#x",function(){...});` call `.toggle()` on `mini-content` element. Of course, the initial visibility of mini-content must be 'hidden'.